# Simple user-facing logging console in HTML / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, console

Does anyone know of a user-facing logging console written in JS? Ideally, I'm looking to be able to write messages with different logging levels (hopefully displayed with different / customizable colors), letting the user scroll through previous messages, and letting the user being able to sort through those messages. In other words, an error console as seen in most IDEs, i.e.:

[image]

I've tried searching for quite a while, but as you might imagine all searches for ("Javascript Console") and its many permutations refer me to the console built into a browser, not one that can be embedded into a webpage for all to see.

Comment: Are you looking for built in stuff like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Comment: Kind of. That's the debug console built into the browser, I believe. I don't want to have to pipe messages from that console into the webpage since filtering it will get messy, and it becomes much more difficult if I want to have two separate consoles, say to log from two different sources.

Comment: I've read some posts where you can overload the console.log to do whatever you want then call the old console, so it still logs properly. If you overload it, then you could in theory store the data however you want and do whatever sorting, searching, etc you want on it

Comment: I'd like this to not be tied to the `console.{method}` at all.